# Fuzzy query doesn't work on text type, but works on keyword type

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have a query that works only on keyword type and I can't figured out why.

However, if I use a Match query plus a fuzziness parameter I can make it work with the text type.

Why is this happening?

Please see find the queries below

(the working query should return Eddie's documents.)

**1) FUZZY QUERY TEXT TYPE -> NOT WORKING**

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "customer_first_name": {
        "value": "Eddi",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2) FUZZY QUERY KEYWORD TYPE - WORKING**

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "customer_first_name.keyword": {
        "value": "Eddi",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**3) MATCH QUERY + FUZINESS -> WORKING**

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "customer_first_name.keyword": {
        "query": "Eddi",
        "fuzziness": "Auto"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**INDEX SETTINGS**

```
{
      "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce" : {
        "aliases" : { },
        "mappings" : {
          "properties" : {
            "category" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "currency" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "customer_birth_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "customer_first_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "customer_full_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "customer_gender" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "customer_id" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "customer_last_name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "customer_phone" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "day_of_week" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "day_of_week_i" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "email" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "geoip" : {
              "properties" : {
                "city_name" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "continent_name" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "country_iso_code" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "location" : {
                  "type" : "geo_point"
                },
                "region_name" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "manufacturer" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "order_date" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "order_id" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "products" : {
              "properties" : {
                "_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "base_price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "base_unit_price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "category" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "created_on" : {
                  "type" : "date"
                },
                "discount_amount" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "discount_percentage" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "manufacturer" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "min_price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "product_id" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "product_name" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword"
                    }
                  },
                  "analyzer" : "english"
                },
                "quantity" : {
                  "type" : "integer"
                },
                "sku" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "tax_amount" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "taxful_price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "taxless_price" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                },
                "unit_discount_amount" : {
                  "type" : "half_float"
                }
              }
            },
            "sku" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "taxful_total_price" : {
              "type" : "half_float"
            },
            "taxless_total_price" : {
              "type" : "half_float"
            },
            "total_quantity" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "total_unique_products" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "user" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "settings" : {
          "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : "1",
            "auto_expand_replicas" : "0-1",
            "provided_name" : "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce",
            "creation_date" : "1579684918696",
            "number_of_replicas" : "0",
            "uuid" : "Ga3UfyyAQjGpa5JDbJB7Sw",
            "version" : {
              "created" : "7050299"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using a custom analyzer? mind posting your index settings?

Comment: is a good question, but no, it is the standard analyzer

Comment: Are there other matches being returned or none?

Comment: @tomslabbaert no matches being returned for the not working query. I've added the index settings so you can see. This index is the default kibana_sample_data_ecommerce, that you load from kibana

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it's happening, but my guess is that its due to how fuziness "rewrites" the query, when you use the `.keyword` `eddie` is chosen in the top 50 and without it, well it's not. can you try running the original query with `max_expansions: 200` maybe? my guess that it'll work.

Comment: @tomslabbaert I tried the query 1) with max_expansions: 200 but it didn't worked. Maybe the answer is related with what you said but still something is missing in the puzzle

Comment: Sorry, that was my last idea. as you said it could be related, imo its worth looking into that direction.

Comment: I Believe I found it out @tomslabbaert, It was a tricky one. I used Explain API. And noticed that when searching fuzzy for text, my text is analyzed and the search finds "eddie" but my query was "Eddi", and therefore the edit distance to eddie is 2. 1 for lowercasing E, and 2 for adding an "e" at the end. This is because Fuzzy Query is a term level query and therefore the query is not analyzed. If I lowercase my query, I get results because eddi -> eddie is exactly 1 edit distance. I THINK I GOT IT

Comment: thank you for this brainstorm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuzzy Query is a Term Level Query. Which means that queries are not analyzed.

**WHY QUERY 1) FAILS**

If you query for "Eddi" it will be compared with analyzed text, in this case "eddie".

And from 'Eddi' to 'eddie' it is a 2 edits distance.

Hence the query will not succeed because terms between 3 and 5 length have the max edit distance is 1 (with the "fuzziness: AUTO" configuration)

**WHY QUERY 2) SUCCEDS**

In other hand if you use Keyword, Keywords are store without being analyzed. and therefore. Eddi is a 1 edit distance from Eddie.